# i have installed queens(openstack),but it's neutron agent only support linuxbridge,how can i replace it by supporting ovs one?

Tags: openstack

```
[root@controller keystone]# openstack user create --domain default --password-prompt neutron
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_domain_name'

[root@controller keystone]# openstack user create --demo default --password-prompt neutron
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_domain_name'

[root@controller keystone]# openstack role add --project service --user neutron admin
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_domain_name'

[root@controller keystone]# openstack service create --name neutron \
  --description "OpenStack Networking" network
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_domain_name'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provide enough information and I believe the title and the body of your question are completely two different issues.

First about your title, I suggest reading [ovs-selfservice](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/latest/admin/deploy-ovs-selfservice.html) for understanding of how ovs-agent works and should be setup. And if you have to migrate from linuxbridge to ovs, follow the instructions on [Migrate OpenStack from Linux Bridge to Open vSwitch](https://blog.51cto.com/u_8493144/1983211)

About the "user_domain_name" issue, I think the source of the problem lies in your openrc file. something like [Bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1628239)

Comment: thanks for your help, your suggestions benefit me so much. About title, the instrutions are useful;and about the text ,i need to learn more to solve the problem that  i have met.thank u.